# recursive requestAnimationFrame() javascript loop jumps directly to the end

Tags: javascript, function, animation, recursion

I'm trying to learn animating in javascript.

I have a path array with x and y coordinates that I try to move through with recursion. But instead of moving the box (box[1]) one step at a time it jumps directly to the last position. If i add an alert in the loop then the animation will "work", so that it just moves the box one step at a time between each alert.

```
function followPath(){
    box1[1].style.left = path[index][0]+'px';
    box1[1].style.top = path[index][1]+'px';
    index++; //I put an alert("hi"); here and it "worked"
    if(index < path.length)
         requestAnimationFrame(followPath());

}

function buttonPress(){
    index = 0;
    followPath();
}
```

What causes this?

As a sidenote, I had the same sort of problem when i tried to pass variables to a similar recursive function that worked just fine before i tried to pass variables to it.

Thanks.

Comment: Try removin () from "followPath()" on the line
    requestAnimationFrame(followPath());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argument to [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) is a function, not what function returns. The line:

```
requestAnimationFrame(followPath());
```

should be

```
requestAnimationFrame(followPath);
```